# ¿Qué quiere decir "piolo" en Argentina?

Tags: coloquialismos, argentina, vulgaridades, lenguaje-peyorativo

Al hilo del Mundial de fútbol y los partidos de preparación, la España twittera ha descubierto el cuán creativos son los seguidores argentinos, especialmente cuando se trata de criticar cómo se desempeñó su selección en un partido.

El artículo [*La creatividad de los argentinos para insultar a su selección, explicada por lingüistas*](https://verne.elpais.com/verne/2018/06/22/articulo/1529648867_962787.html) de hoy mismo habla de ello y os invito a pasearos por la lista, pues no tiene desperdicio.

Un efecto secundario de esto es que las expresiones más fascinantes reciben muchos "me gusta" y retuits, así es que [uno de ellos añadió](https://twitter.com/JoniAbascal/status/1009888784052342785):

> Gallegos dejen de darme RT que me rompen el movil PIOLOS COMEBOLSAS

Con *gallegos* se refiere a los españoles. Con *RT* al acto de retuitear (compartir) lo dicho, pero lo de *piolos comebolsas*, aparte de ser un insulto bastante grosero, no lo entendí.

Estando preparado desde ya para leer una definición bastante hiriente, ¿qué quiere decir *piolo*?

Lo único que encontré [en el DAMER](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=piolo) es una acepción cubana que dice *Persona de raza negra, que solo quiere tener relaciones amorosas con personas de raza blanca*.

Comment: ¿No será una palabra oscena italiana?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dice @rsanchez en su respuesta, el autor es español y está tratando de parodiar. Una de las pistas es que usa la palabra *móvil* para hablar de su teléfono, siendo que en Argentina al dispositivo en cuestión se le dice *celular*.

*Piolo* no significa nada en Argentina. Quizá el bromista haya oído mal la palabra *piola* (adjetivo invariable en género), que es un término coloquial (no malsonante) ya algo pasado de moda y que significa una serie de cosas desde "buena onda" hasta "que se da maña", o también "despierto, vivo, astuto".

*Comebolsas* es evidentemente una construcción del tipo de las que aparecen en los "insultos argentinos", género que por lo que veo se ha vuelto popular en España. Tengo que decir que creo que se está forzando bastante el asunto (en Argentina nadie habla así, es léxico de una pequeña burbuja en las redes sociales).

Answer (score 2):

Ni *piolo* ni *comebolsas* quieren decir nada en particular en Argentina. El autor de la frase [es de Santander](https://twitter.com/JoniAbascal/status/1010123361891094530):

> Soy de Santander salu2, pero se nota que tú no pillas las bromas

Con su frase quiso [parodiar el estilo de los insultos Argentinos](https://twitter.com/JoniAbascal/status/1010142239115407360):

> Lo cojonudo que soy de españa que solo puse el tweet por las risas la mítica broma, por lo de argentina, y la gente está enferma ajajaajajaj se piensan que twitter es Facebook que poca cultura ajajajaajajajajaja

Comment: ¡Oh! Aunque de todos modos, ¿tiene significado _piolo_ en Argentina?

Comment: @fedorqui no, pensé que quedó claro en la primera oración